# Python3 requests module or urllib.request module both retrieving incomplete json

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm doing some scraping and looking at pages like this one (https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/20261627/workouts/526622897), but I have not been able to fully retrieve the JSON content.I have tried using both of the following sets of code, but each returns an incomplete JSON object:

```
    url = 'https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/%s/workouts/%s'%(string_use_user, string_use_workout)
    print(url)
    response = urlopen(url)
    try:
        reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
        print(reader(response))
        jsonresponse = json.load(reader(response))
        print(jsonresponse)
```

and similarly using the response library instead of urllib also fails to retrieve the full JSON

```
    url = 'https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/%s/workouts/%s'%(string_use_user, string_use_workout)
    print("using this url %s"%url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    try:
        print(r.json())
        jsonresponse = r.json()# json.loads(response.read())
```

In both cases I get about 1/4 of the JSON. For example, in this case:
https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/20261627/workouts/526622897

I received:

```
{'feed_id': 281475471235835, 'id': 526622897, 'duration': 4082.0, 'local_start_time': '2015-05-21T09:30:45.000+02:00', 'calories': 1073.0, 'tagged_users': [], 'altitude_max': 69.9523, 'sport': 0, 'distance': 11.115419387817383, 'altitud\
e_min': 14.9908, 'include_in_stats': True, 'hydration': 0.545339, 'start_time': '2015-05-21T07:30:45.000Z', 'ascent': 137.162, 'is_live': False, 'pb_count': 2, 'playlist': [], 'is_peptalk_allowed': False, 'weather': {'wind_speed': 11, '\
temperature': 12, 'wind_direction': 13, 'type': 3, 'humidity': 81}, 'speed_max': 24.8596, 'author': {'name': 'gfdgfd', 'id': 20261627, 'last_name': 'gdsgsk', 'gender': 0, 'expand': 'abs', 'picture': {'url': 'https://www.endom\
ondo.com/resources/gfx/picture/18511427/thumbnail.jpg'}, 'first_name': 'gdsgds', 'viewer_friendship': 1, 'is_premium': False}, 'sharing': [{'share_time': '2015-05-21T08:45:19.000Z', 'type': 0, 'share_id': 1635690786663532}], 'show_map':\
 0, 'pictures': [], 'hashtags': [], 'descent': 150.621, 'speed_avg': 9.80291763746756, 'expand': 'full', 'show_workout': 0, 'points': {'expand': 'ref', 'id': 2199549878449}}
```

I am not receiving the long arrays within the data. I am also not even recovering all of the non-array data.

I ran the original page through a JSON validator, and it's fine. Similarly, I ran the JSON I do receive through a validator, and it's also fine - it doesn't show any signs of missing things unless I compare with the original.

I would appreciate any advice about how to troubleshoot this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this API is doing some [User-Agent sniffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_sniffing) and only sending the complete content for what it considers to be actual web browsers.

Once you set a `User-Agent` header with the UA string of a common browser, you get the full response:

```
>>> UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
>>> url = 'https://www.endomondo.com/rest/v1/users/20261627/workouts/526622897'
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': UA})
>>>
>>> print len(r.content)
96412
```

See the `requests` docs for more details on [setting custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).